# Select Grandchild and Grandparent names

Tags: sql, database

So i have a Kings table with schema:

name(PK)

I have a Parents table with schema
child(FK)|parent(FK)

1)I need to get the names of a child and its grandparent.

**Parent table:**

**child | Parent**

RAZMIAH | RAZALI

RAZALI  | SABUR

REZWAN | SABUR

**Kings Table:**

**name**

RAZMIAH

RAZALI

RAZEM

REZWAN

Expected:
Razmiah| Sabur

Attempt:

```
SELECT a.name, q.parent
FROM KINGS a, parents p
where a.name = p.child 
and p.parent in (
        select q.child
        from kings c, parents q
        where c.name = q.child)
```

The multi-part identifier "q.parent" could not be bound.

Comment: For better answer tag the DBMS and provide some sample and desired output data. Are the both columns of parent table referring the same KING table's (NAME) column ?

Answer (score 0):

PK means primary key, FK means Foreign key. please check the relation according to this and change the query

Answer (score 0):

This will address your requirement, please try this:

```
SELECT a1.name AS childName, a.name AS parentName
FROM parents p
LEFT JOIN KINGS a ON a.name = p.parent 
LEFT JOIN KINGS a1 ON a1.name = p.child
```

Comment: but p.parent is just a parent right? i want the grandparent

Comment: Yes, it just gives you error free code please post sample data so that we can address your complete requirement.

Comment: Sorry, we had this weird rule not to use the join keyword

Answer (score 0):

Nvm i got it!

```
select p.child, q.parent
from parents p, parents q
where p.parent = q.child
```